# macOS: aws cli Could not find executable named "groff"

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli

I'm on macOS and attempting to view help for `aws ec2` and I get:

```bash
aws ec2 help
# Could not find executable named "groff"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you see this, groff isn't installed. [Groff](https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/groff) can be installed on macOS like so:

```bash
brew install groff
```

(If using another operating system, try your OS's package manager - e.g. `apt install -y groff` for ubuntu (from [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/Crostini/comments/b1gt7p/comment/eilifhs/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3))